# PHP htaccess - allow disallow

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess code in my include files directory to protect against direct access.

```
<Files *>
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This works fine except for one file which is used for my jquery star rating. Ratings are written to and read from a php file.

I need to modify the above htaccess code so ratings.data.php file is excluded from the deny all.

Something Like:

```
<Files *>
Deny from all
    Allow ratings.data.php
</Files>
```

**How can I accomplish this? Thank you for your help!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Allow/Deny directive sets the clients that can access that portion of the site.
So you would need to add another  section with something like:

```
<Files ratings.data.php>
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

**Update:** Some clarification.

You need to add both sections:

```
<Files ratings.data.php>
    Allow from all
    Order Allow,Deny
</Files>

<Files *>
    Deny from all
    Order Deny,Allow
</Files>
```

Comment: This just allows access to all files.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<Files ratings.data.php>
Satisfy All  
</Files>`
```